# Type system in Clojure

Tags: clojure, duck-typing

Is the "programming to abstractions" principle in Clojure the same as duck typing? If not, what are the differences?

Here is a quote from http://www.braveclojure.com/core-functions-in-depth/:

> The reason is that Clojure defines map and reduce functions in terms of the 
>   sequence abstraction, not in terms of specific data structures. As
>   long as a data structure responds to the core sequence operations (the
>   functions first, rest, and cons, which we’ll look at more closely in a
>   moment), it will work with map, reduce, and oodles of other sequence
>   functions for free. This is what Clojurists mean by programming to
>   abstractions, and it’s a central tenet of Clojure philosophy.
>
> I think of abstractions as named collections of operations. If you can
>   perform all of an abstraction’s operations on an object, then that
>   object is an instance of the abstraction. I think this way even
>   outside of programming. For example, the battery abstraction includes
>   the operation “connect a conducting medium to its anode and cathode,”
>   and the operation’s output is electrical current. It doesn’t matter if
>   the battery is made out of lithium or out of potatoes. It’s a battery
>   as long as it responds to the set of operations that define battery.

Data types are identified to be part of the abstract class by behaviour ("responds to"). Isn't this the essence of duck typing? Thanks for input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the "programming to abstractions" principle in Clojure the same as
>   duck typing?

**No**.

- Clojure is defined in terms of [Extensible Abstractions](https://clojure.org/about/functional_programming#_extensible_abstractions).
- These are Java interfaces ...
- ... which are used most prominently to define the core data
  structures.

For example, the sequence abstraction is defined by [`clojure.lang.ISeq`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/ISeq.java):

```
public interface ISeq extends IPersistentCollection {
  Object first();
  ISeq next();
  ISeq more();
  ISeq cons(Object o);
}
```

Any class that implements `ISeq` is accepted by Clojure as a sequence (whether is behaves properly is another matter). For example, lists and lazy sequences do so, and are treated impartially as sequences. Contrast this with classic Lisp, where a different set of functions apply to each.

And we have several different implementations of vectors

- the core clojure vector type;
- rrb vectors;
- fast small vectors.

I could go on. (Actually, I can't. I don't know enough!)

Comment: by "no" here you must mean "yes" as your explanation goes on to explain exactly how Clojure's "extensible abstractions" are its ducks.

Comment: @NeverSleepAgain [Alan Malloy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43841095/1562315) explains why Clojure's "extensible abstractions" are *not* its ducks.

Comment: he states "Merely implementing appropriately-named methods is not enough, as it is in, say, Python, a typical duck-typing language" and he is incorrect, or I am misreading. Will Clojure refuse to compile a method that doesn't return the right type of thing, or refuse to select next()-returning-Frog when next()-returning-Iseq is needed? Because "merely implementing appropriately-named methods" is not enough in an openly duck-typing language either, for a definition of "enough" that means the program not only compiles but works. C++ for instance chooses between identically named methods.

Answer (score 4):

> Data types are identified to be part of the abstract class by behaviour ("responds to").

They're not, though. On the JVM, types can only be part of an interface if they explicitly state that they implement the interface, and then implement its methods. Merely implementing appropriately-named methods is not enough, as it is in, say, Python, a typical duck-typing language.

What's written is not exactly *wrong*, but it requires a bit of a specific viewpoint to interpret it as correct: you must realize that when the author writes,

> As long as a data structure responds to the core sequence operations...

What is meant is that the type must implement the core sequence interfaces and their methods. In a way, merely exposing a function named `first` is *not* enough to "respond" to the same-named core sequence operation: the type must also implement the right interface in order to "respond". It's a weird way to write things in a VM that's not framed in terms of responding to messages, and requires some expertise and squinting to find a correct meaning in, but it's a reasonable simplification for beginners, who don't need to know about the details yet...unless they are inclined to ask Stack Overflow questions about duck typing!